# Determine Which Landscape mode to set Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms I'm using dependency service, to force the screen to orient on Landscape mode by using the code below.

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft), new NSString("orientation"));
```

But how to determine whether to orient in Landscape Right or Landscape Left

**UPDATE**
When the user is holding the device in landscape right and wants to lock the orientation in the landscape, the device gets locked in Landscape Left. So how to intelligently find which position to lock it in? If I lock it in Landscape left it won't work when the user holds it in Landscape Right and vice versa.

[Found this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62004), equivalent of this would work, But not sure how to do it in Xamarin.iOS

Comment: You have already set as`UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft`, what do you mean about how to determine whether to orient in Landscape Right or Landscape Left?

Comment: When the user is holding the device in landscape right and wants to lock the orientation in the landscape, the device gets locked in Landscape Left. So how to intelligently find which position to lock it in? If I lock it in Landscape left it won't work when the user holds it in Landscape Right and vice versa.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could detect the device orientation according to `StatusBarOrientation` in the iOS platform before locking the orientation. Then you can lock the orientation according to user's current orientation.

```
    var currentOrientation = UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation;

    if (currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
    {
        //YOUR CODE
    }
    else if (currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    {
        //YOUR CODE
    }
```

Reference: [Checking Device Orientation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/device-orientation/#iOS_Implementation)

**Update**:

When the screen orientation is locked, you need an old but useful tool to detect the orientation. It is [Core Motion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion). For example, you can use it like this:

```
        public void LockOrientation()
        {
            CMMotionManager CMManager = new CMMotionManager();
            CMManager.DeviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.2f;
            CMManager.StartDeviceMotionUpdates(NSOperationQueue.MainQueue, (motion, error) => {
                if (Math.Abs(motion.Gravity.X) > Math.Abs(motion.Gravity.Y))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Lan");
                    if (motion.Gravity.X > 0)
                    {
                        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft), new NSString("orientation"));
                        Console.WriteLine("Left");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight), new NSString("orientation"));
                        Console.WriteLine("Right");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (motion.Gravity.Y >= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Down");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("UP");
                    }
                }

                CMManager.StopDeviceMotionUpdates();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Already tried this. currentOrientation would always be portrait since it's already locked in portrait orientation.

Comment: I have updated my answer and provide a solution for locking orientation scenario.

Comment: @FemilShajin, did my answer help you?

Comment: Hey sorry, forgot to revert back. No, it didn't help. Motion updates are only received only when I rotate the device. Maybe I Haven't explained it properly.

App is locked in portrait, so user rotates to landscape and then locks it in landscape mode(Clicking on a switch), so rotation already happened and motion updates won't run when it was locked on potrait. Thanks but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried it? It works fine for me. After user rotates the device which locks in portrait to landscape, user can click a button which trigger the method I provided, the screen will be locked at current status.

Comment: I add the line `CMManager.StopDeviceMotionUpdates();` which will stop update the device motion update at the end of this method. If remove it, it will continue detecting the device orientation.